# Is nearly 50% of Planned Parenthood's earned revenue from abortion?

Tags: abortion, planned-parenthood

According to [Planned Parenthood's annual report](http://www.plannedparenthood.org/files/6714/1996/2641/2013-2014_Annual_Report_FINAL_WEB_VERSION.pdf) on page 18, they carried out 327,653 abortions in 2013.

The Guttmacher Institute says the [average price paid for an abortion is $451](http://www.guttmacher.org/in-the-know/abortion-costs.html).

This means Planned Parenthood makes upwards of $140 million each year from abortions.

The annual report says on page 21 their revenue from non-governmental health services is $305.3 million. That means 45% of this revenue is from abortion.

The rest of their revenue comes from federal funding and donations, except a $77.9 million from "other operating revenue".

In my mind, there is a difference between revenue from charging a client and revenue from funding and donations.  The first is similar to how a for-profit company makes money for products and services rendered, which I would call "earned income".  The second is like donations given to a non-profit company, which do not seem earned in the same way.  I do not know enough about for-profit and non-profit companies to use better terminology.

Is it correct then to say that almost 50% of Planned Parenthoods earned revenue is from abortion?

Comment: Arithmetic quibble: median is not the same as mean. You can't multiply median price by number performed and expect to get total revenue. The figures you quote are consistent with the total revenue from abortions being as low as $77 million or as high as infinity.

Comment: The average is $450.

Comment: What is the source for that number?

Comment: The same link http://www.guttmacher.org/in-the-know/abortion-costs.html

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a notable claim, widely believed, but instead your speculation. If you want us to investigate the financial report, explain which figure you doubt.

Comment: Wikipedia [answers this question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_Parenthood).

Comment: @yters: Thanks. There's another logical gap, though. It looks like the Guttmacher number is an average for all abortions, across all providers. We do not know that this average is representative of the price charged by PP in particular - their average price could be higher or lower.

Comment: @Oddthinking, that 50% stat makes it look like abortion is a crucial part of how Planned Parenthood makes its money.  However, Planned Parenthood often downplays the importance of abortion for its business model, such as the 3% stat referenced in http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28661/do-abortions-make-up-only-3-of-planned-parenthoods-services/28674?noredirect=1#comment109480_28674.  Anti-abortion groups often say Planned Parenthood is an abortion business, and I suspect they are correct: http://pptrubiz.blogspot.com/2015/07/planned-parenthoods-true-business-is.html

Comment: @Oddthinking, the claim that Planned Parenthood's business model is fundamentally to provide abortions is notable, and is challenged by Planned Parenthood.  I will reword the question to explain the notable claim better.

Comment: @yters You need to be careful with how you are approaching things. Planned Parenthood is a non-profit, so their objective is not to realize a profit but to have enough income to continue to provide their services. Most of the services that they provide are either free or extremely low cost so it a service that they have to charge money for is going to drive most of their revenue.

Comment: @rjzii, being a non-profit does not mean the employees of Planned Parenthood do not make a lot of money for themselves from abortion.  An article by Abby Johnson states an abortionist she worked for made between $3-4k a day by doing abortions.

Comment: @yters That would only be a single data point and without seeing the article in question I can't evaluate the quality of the citation either. It also doesn't refute my point either: the income from one service could be enough to support the majority of their other operations.

Comment: @yters: The 50% stat is (a) heavily influenced by your arbitrary discounting of all the other revenue received, and (b) still not a notable claim because no-one else but you is claiming that it is true or false.

Comment: [Is 20% of Planned Parenthood's revenue from abortion?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28675) -- @Oddthinking: Perhaps change the closing reason to dupe?